# How to pass multiple ids in batches and than merge it in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have below mentioned dataframe in R.

DF1

```
ID       Sales         Cost       Value
RTT-123  10            10000      15000
RTT-456  15            12000      17000
RTT-789  14            14000      19000
```

The dataframe containst almost ~30K unique Ids, while passing these ids to redshift using below mentioned query, I am getting error `Error in .verify.JDBC.result(r, "Unable to retrieve JDBC result set for ",  :`

How to pass these Ids automatically in the batch of 2K ids while querying and then merge the output to one single data frame in R.

Query:

```
df2<-paste0("SELECT ID,list1,list2, date1 FROM table1 b
            WHERE b.ID IN (", paste(shQuote(DF1$ID , type = "sh"),collapse = ','),");")

output<-dbGetQuery(link,df2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this (not tested), here we are using 1000 IDs at a time, adjust as per your needs:

```
library(data.table) # rbindlist

output <- rbindlist(
  lapply(
    # 1000 chunks
    split(DF1$ID, ceiling(seq_along(DF1$ID)/1000)), 
    function(i){
      df2 <- paste0("SELECT ID,list1,list2, date1 FROM table1 b
                     WHERE b.ID IN (",
                    paste(shQuote(i , type = "sh"), collapse = ','),
                    ");")
      dbGetQuery(link, df2)
    }))
```